# Unable to save file to Amazon S3 when using carrierwave

Tags: upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave, rmagick, fog

SEE UPDATE BELOW!

I am having problems after I upload an image file to Amazon S3 and then try to save the file.

I use direct_fog_url(with_path: true) to get the the url of the image uploaded.  I then get the following error:

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Validation failed: Image could not download file

I saw these two possible solutions:

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/700

http://www.github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/888

But neither one seems to work.

Im using the older deleted command: overwriting method process_uri (enter link description here):

```
def process_uri(uri) 
 URI.parse(URI.escape(URI.unescape(uri)).gsub("[", "%5B").gsub("]", "%5D").gsub("+", "%2B"))
end
```

In my application I am using the following Gems:

gem 'fog'

gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'carrierwave_direct'

gem 'rmagick'

Thanks!

UPDATE: After implementing @Alex's answer below we resolved that problem but now when we do the upload we get the following error:

Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently

PermanentRedirect
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your **Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently** issue, make sure that you have the right data center region configured in your carrierwave.rb file. For example, if you're hosted on us-west, your region needs to be set to us-west.

Comment: What you said was the issue.  It turns out that the problem was legacy issues with AWS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691881/301-moved-permanently-after-s3-uploading

Answer (score 1):

Have you found a solution to this problem yet?

I'm facing the same problem here, I'm trying to fetch a remote URL with carrierwave (not on S3) and I get the notorious 'could not download file' error:

```
    Validation failed: Image could not download file
    [...]/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
```

Could you post your URL to see what special characters there are?

EDIT: I found a solution. My case required that I did *not* change or escape the uri at all. I found that by adding 'return' to the 'def process_uri(uri)' method it works just fine.
Just in case this is useful to someone else, this is my overriding method in my uploader class:

```
    def process_uri(uri)
      return URI.parse(uri)
    end
```

Comment: This seems to resolve the first issue for us, but now we are getting a new error: PermanentRedirect
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

Comment: Just to clarify, adding "return" shouldn't make any difference in Ruby code. The last command in the method will automatically return.